# How to use IPC to send Slack app a message

Tags: http, ipc, slack, slack-api

If I have Slack as a desktop app running on my local machine, is there a way for me to send it a message from another locally running process?

My goal is to use the regular Slack api to ping channels, etc. But instead of using a standard integration, I could do it from another local process. Maybe Slack is listening on localhost?

If the above concept doesn't work, is the only other way to do a Slack integration, where I would send a payload to Slack servers?

note: I said "IPC" in the question, but most likely it would be HTTP/TCP to send a message from my process to the slack process on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not send your local running Slack client a "direct" message from another local running app. A Slack client is just a viewer for a Slack workspace that is running in the cloud. It does not listen to local IPC messages.

There are many ways how to send a message with the Slack API. I would suggest to start with looking at [incoming webhook](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks). This only requires you to send a POST HTTP request to a URL provided by Slack.

Comment: any idea why slack would not listen on localhost for messages? seems like a nice way to do custom integrations

Comment: My guess is it does not fit to their architecture, which is a cloud centric and platform agnostic. And they are already providing the feature you are looking for (sending message) through their existing API. In other words: The Slack desktop app is not a server that can listen on a socket, but just a client.

Comment: I agree, that makes sense. t's probably cause they want to limit the number of integrations, so they can get people to pay for their software, which is fine

Comment: Sure. They are a company and want to sell their product. But, I wonder what problem you want to solve?

Comment: I am trying to show notifications in slack when developers are working on the same files - it's a warning to help prevent merge conflicts. I also want to put notifications in jetbrains and vscode etc.

Comment: Good idea. And you can do all that within one Slack app.

Comment: writing a vscode plugin is easy, writing a jetbrains/intellij plugin is very hard, a testament to node.js being easy to use

Comment: It seems silly that a client app (mine) has to deal with api keys and web service endpoints to send a message to another app (Slack) which is on the same machine. It introduces a whole layer of authentication which is really unnecessary. Imagine having to do all that to run any two other processes. It’s silly.